# Where to get UTF-8 charset

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I need to get the complete list of UTF-8 charset from some authorized locations.

I've tried looking at Unicode.org but with not info.

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "UTF-8 charset"? UTF-8 is an *encoding* - used to represent Unicode characters as sequences of bytes.

Comment: Please read wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Or perhaps this one:
http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html

Comment: I find it, but Is this a standard authority?

Comment: I don't think so but I added a second link directly from unicode.org

Answer (score 2):

The set of characters representable in UTF-8 is exactly the same as the set of Unicode characters.

The authority is the Unicode Consortium. If you specifically want a list, then you can visit http://www.unicode.org/ucd/ which links to the Unicode Character Database, containing the large list http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt . It is not a completely explicit list, though, since some wide ranges are indicated just as ranges, e.g.

```
AC00;<Hangul Syllable, First>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
D7A3;<Hangul Syllable, Last>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
```

which means that characters from AC00 to D7A3 are all defined to be Hangul syllable characters (with names to be constructured algorithmically).

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732025/why-degree-symbol-differs-from-utf-8-from-unicode cause I am very very confused!