# Why does the 'degree' symbol differ from UTF-8 from Unicode?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

Why does *degree* symbol differ from UTF-8 from Unicode?

According to http://www.utf8-chartable.de/  and
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm, Unicode is **B0**, but UTF-8 is **C2 B0** How come?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between Unicode and its various encodings. Read the links people have posted.

Comment: Do you mean *"Why does the 'degree' symbol differ between UTF-8 and the [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)?"*?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

UTF-8 is a way to encode UTF characters using variable number of bytes (the number of bytes depends on the code point).

Code points between U+0080 and U+07FF use the following 2-byte [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design):

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

where `x` represent the bits of the code point being encoded.

Let's consider U+00B0. In binary, 0xB0 is 10110000. If one substitutes the bits into the above template, one gets:

```
 11000010 10110000
```

In hex, this is 0xC2 0xB0.

Comment: And, crucially, that is simply a different representation of the same Unicode code point, U+00B0.  UTF-16 uses 0x00 0xB0 (big-endian) or 0xB0 0x00 (little-endian), but UTF-8 uses 0xC2 0xB0 (no endian-ness).

Comment: The link you provide is very helpful ... Thanks

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "No endian-ness" Not proper terminology but funny

Comment: @Userthatisnotauser It is the proper terminology. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @clake Sorry, I was referring to the odd placement of the dash. Definitely agree! ‍♂️

Answer (score 8):

UTF-8 is one encoding of Unicode.  UTF-16 and UTF-32 are other encodings of Unicode.

Unicode defines a numeric value for each character; the degree symbol happens to be 0xB0, or 176 in decimal.  Unicode does not define how those numeric values are represented.

UTF-8 encodes the value `0xB0` as two consecutive octets (bytes) with values `0xC2 0xB0`.

UTF-16 encodes the same value either as `0x00 0xB0` or as `0xB0 0x00`, depending on endianness.

UTF-32 encodes it as `0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB0` or as `0xB0 0x00 0x00 0x00`, again depending on endianness (I suppose other orderings are possible).

Answer (score 5):

Unicode (UTF-16 and UTF-32) uses the code point `0x00B0` for that character. UTF-8 doesn't allow characters at values above 127 (`0x007F`), as the high bit of each byte is reserved to indicate that this particular character is actually a multi-byte one.

Basic 7-bit ASCII maps directly to the first 128 characters of UTF-8. Any characters whose values are above 127 decimal (7F hex) must be "escaped" by setting the high bit and adding 1 or more extra bytes to describe.

Answer (score 1):

The answers from NPE, Marc and Keith are good and above my knowledge on this topic. Still I had to read them a couple of times before I realized what this was about. Then I saw this web page that made it "click" for me.

At http://www.utf8-chartable.de/, you can see the following:

[image: UTF-8 needs C2 80 to represent U+0080]

Notice how it is necessary to use TWO bytes to code ONE character. Now read the accepted answer from NPE.

Comment: If a user can't see the website, it shows `0x7F` (DELETE) as UTF-8: `7F`, and `0x80` <control> as UTF-8: `C2 80`