# Unicode Characters in URL

Tags: url, unicode

Can I use all unicode characters except ascii chatacters  in url such as cyrillic character,  latin extension IPA extension etc.? 
if so, how can I use those unicode characters in the url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can urls have UTF-8 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357509/can-urls-have-utf-8-characters)

Comment: URIs/URLs can only have ASCII characters in them. Non-ASCII characters (and reserved ASCII characters) *must* be encoded to ASCII (using IDN in the hostname, or percent-encoding in the rest). In the case of percent-encoding, there is no standard for which charset to actually use, that is up to the webserver to decide.  UTF-8 is most commonly used, but I have seen other charsets being used, too.  IRIs, on the other hand, support non-encoded Unicode characters, and dictate UTF-8 when converting to URIs/URLs

Answer (score 2):

As [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) said in comments:

> URIs/URLs can only have ASCII characters in them. Non-ASCII characters
> (and reserved ASCII characters) must be encoded to ASCII (using IDN in
> the hostname, or percent-encoding in the rest). In the case of
> percent-encoding, there is no standard for which charset to actually
> use, that is up to the webserver to decide. UTF-8 is most commonly
> used, but I have seen other charsets being used, too. IRIs, on the
> other hand, support non-encoded Unicode characters, and dictate UTF-8
> when converting to URIs/URLs